# append a json string to a file

Tags: java, json

How to append a json string to a file that already contains json strings(in java)?
I tried reading the file into memory using objectmapper and then append it and put it back into file.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
HashMap<String, Object> jsonMap = mapper.readValue( new File(workflowSessionFilePath), new TypeReference<HashMap<String, Object>>() {});

jsonMap.put("key", "value");
mapper.defaultPrettyPrintingWriter().writeValue(new File(workflowSessionFilePath), jsonMap);
```

But is there a better way than this?

Comment: How do you parse and modify the content of the file? Please provide code samples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Methods in java.nio.Files:

```
public static Path write(Path path,
                         Iterable<? extends CharSequence> lines,
                         Charset cs,
                         OpenOption... options)

public static BufferedWriter newBufferedWriter(Path path,
                                               Charset cs,
                                               OpenOption... options)
```

If options excludes CREATE, then existing file is opened, but new file never created.
If options excludes TRUNCATE, then existing content is kept and new content is appended.

Calls:

```
java.nio.Files.write(new Path(...),
                     myOutputString,  // or StringBuffer/StringBuilder/Charbuffer
                     myCharset,       // e.g. java.nio.charset.Charset.forName("UTF8")
                     java.nio.file.StandardOpenOption.WRITE);


BufferedWriter bw =  java.nio.files.Files.newBufferedWriter(
                                               new Path(...),
                                               myCharset,
                                               java.nio.file.StandardOpenOption.WRITE);
for (...) {
      bw.write(...);
}
bw.flush();
bw.close();
```